# Jpql: Having without Group By

Tags: postgresql, jpql

I have (working) SQL query

```sql
   select team
   from team
   join account a on team.account_id = a.id
   left join exchange_order eo on a.id = eo.account_id
   left join exchange_order_transaction eot on eo.id = eot.order_id
   having count(eot.id) = 0;
```

and want translate it to jpql

```java
    @Query("SELECT COUNT(t) " +
            "FROM Team t " +
            "         left join Account a on t.account = a.id " +
            "         left join ExchangeOrder eo on a.id = eo.account " +
            "         left join ExchangeOrderTransaction eot on eo.id = eot.order " +
            "HAVING count(eot) = 0")
    long countWithoutTransactions();
```

Problem is that, seems, JPQL not allow having HAVING without "group by". But in that case
I don't want group anything. Want just count all rows.

Is any way to omnit "group by" or how i should construct that query?

Comment: Please explain the logic behind `having count(eot.id) = 0` ... what is this supposed to be asserting?

Comment: Teams are connected via account via exchange_order with exchange_order_transaction. I want get all teams without any row in exchange_order_transaction  table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to do a left anti-join to the `exchange_order_transaction` table.  Use this query:

```
select team.*
from team
join account a on team.account_id = a.id
left join exchange_order eo on a.id = eo.account_id
left join exchange_order_transaction eot on eo.id = eot.order_id
where eot.id is null;
```

Comment: no, not exactly. i want COUNT teams without exchange_order_transaction. My SQL query working well, just have no idea how translate it to JPQL. How make JPQL with HAVING and without GROUP BY, as I have in SQL.

Comment: Using `COUNT` without `GROUP BY` makes no sense at all.  At this point, you should add sample input and output data to your question to better explain what you are trying to do here.